# capture the Failure mail

Tags: smtp

Is it possible to capture the failure mail. I have created a application for sending mail, i have a log file to store the sent mails. If the sent mail is failure, i just want to find out the failure mail and update the log file.

Is it possible! Is there any way to match the sent mail and the failure mail

Please help me and guide me.

Comment: What language?  What are you using to send mail?  What type of failure (failure within the component or failure on the receiver side)?

Comment: language:cache, SMTP server is used to send mail. Its a failure mail(if we enter the wrong email ID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean by failure, a bounced email, you can add an email address to 'return-path' header. If the email is bounced it will be returned to the the email address specified in the return-path. You can then set up a service to analyze these emails.

Comment: I think the from is default 'return-path'.  Any how tell me how to set "return-path"?

Comment: It depends on the language you're using. Usually it's through some kind  of headers collections.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what client are you using, is it Postfix, sendmail, etc?
And what do you mean by "failure".

The basic approach would  be to use crontab. It can direct error message
to your email, when it fails

```
MAILTO=youremail@foo.net
#
# run five minutes after midnight, every day
5 0 * * $HOME/bin/emailcode
```

If you use sendmail, you can always
verify the log at:

```
/var/log/maillog
```

Comment: Its not a error, actually its a failure mail(if we enter the wrong email ID)